# Why git merge generate two same change history after push the merged commit?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have merged develope branch to master branch, then pushed the origin to remote. As a result there are two same change history and the merged history is the same of the last commit in the develop branch. 
The merged and commited master branch is always 1 commit ahead than develop branch, Why? At last, if I merge the new commit history on master back to develop then two branch will be same and no new commit history is generated.

merged to master branch
https://github.com/uptown1919/cmake/commit/3691a71d83ca3335e6236cdb07cb629fd8c749f1

last change in develop branch
https://github.com/uptown1919/cmake/commit/faac63cf7f754561e2aa46d62dba4e9c232d9996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your repo's history, it looks like you either passed the `--no-ff` option to `git merge`, or you have your configuration set up so that fast forwards are disabled by default. When you do this, a new commit is *always* created when you perform a merge. Combine that with the fact that when you merge, only the branch that you are merging *into* changes, you are left with that branch pointing to the new commit and the branch you merged *from* staying on its existing commit.

Note that even when you do not use the `--no-ff` option, there will be many cases where you merge and a fast forward is not possible. In those cases, you will also have your destination and source branches pointing to different commits.